# Vim capturing groups regex to replace camel case string with blank space at the end

Tags: regex, vim, camelcasing

I have line of code like this one:

```
variableInCamelCase <- map["variableInCamelCase"]
```

I need to make it like this:

```
variable_In_Camel_Case <- map["variableInCameCase"]
```

Only the first word must be converted, I'm trying to find a regex to do it, and I need to do it in Vim but I can't.
A regex like this one:

```
var rex = /([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z])/g;

"CSVFilesAreCoolButTXT".replace( rex, '$1$4_$2$3$5' );
```

Is not good because I need to do it only on the first word. Plus, I need it for VIM which uses a special syntax to capture a group.

I tried something like this: `s/\(\l\)\(\u\)/\1_\2/g`, which is equivalent to `([a-z])([A-Z])`, but I can't put it in OR with the `([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])`

There is someone with a good vim ready regex for my problem? An explanation would be welcome also.

Comment: This is the best I can come up with so far.  Unfortunately, it adds a trailing `_` after the variable name.  I'm still thinking about whether there's a way around that.  `s/\v([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z])|( .*$)/\1\4_\2\3\5\6/g`

Comment: This is an extremely hack solution, but you could do `qq:s/\v^\w{-}\a\zs\u/_&<cr>@qq@q`

Comment: Tim Pope's [abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've got two commands to transform to `snake_case` from `UpperCamelCase` or `lowerCamelCase`, and the other way around, in [lh-dev](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev#commands). One applies on the current word, the other works like `substitute`. Actually more naming choices are available if you configure the library for your current project (-> variables, attributes, constants, getters, types, etc).

How it works? Well it's using the [`lh#dev#naming#to_underscore()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev/blob/master/autoload/lh/dev/naming.vim#L74) function in the case of `CamelCase` -> `snake case`.

This one is quite simple actually:

```
" Function:lh#dev#naming#to_underscore(identifier)         {{{3
function! lh#dev#naming#to_underscore(identifier)
  " first I make sure the first letter is in lower case
  let identifier = substitute(a:identifier, '\%(^\|[^A-Za-z0-9]\)\zs\(\u\)', '\l\1', '')
  " then I replace uppercase letters by '_' + their lower case flavour
  let identifier = substitute(identifier, '\l\zs\(\u\)', '_\l\1', 'g')
  return identifier
endfunction
```

Then, `:[range]ConvertNames/pattern/policy/flag` will be converted into something like `:[range]substitute/pattern/\=lh#dev#naming#{snake}(submatch(0))/flags`.

With a generic pattern like `\w\+`, it'll apply the transformation on the first word found -- the transformation being replacing the word found with its snake case form.